# ImageView Id not being created in R file

Tags: android

Quite new to Android dev so there is a good chance I made a dumb mistake. But for some reason I cant reference a ImageView I created in a second Activity using the findViewById method. When I went and checked the 'R' file I could see that an Id was not created for all 3 ImageViews I am trying to reference that is in the same activity.

What could the possible reason be for this? Could it be something to do with data I put in the Manifest file? My java class? Because my syntax for the containing activity is 100%....

I'm suspecting is has something to do with the new activity/manifest. How can all the ImageViews in the same Activity not be referenced...?

Comment: just clean the project or right click on the project and build the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean the project and try again. To clean you project `Project -> Clean` select your project and clean. Some time it happens while developing the project. I've faced many times.

Comment: So I just tried cleaning the project.. And now my R file completely disappeared. Nooooo!